# Falkner Skan solution using a tridiagonal matrix method. For 0, -ve $\beta$ I get incorrect solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, fluid-dynamics, tridiagonal-matrices

I am trying to solve the Falkner Skan equation for wedge flows numerically, by first reducing it to a second order system and then solving a tridiagonal matrix equation iteratively till solution converges to a required tolerance.
Essentially we have:
$$ f''' + ff'' + \beta(1-f'^2) = 0\\
f(0)= f'(0)=0\\
f'(\infty)=1\\
$$
Here, we take
$$ f' = G$$
And the equation becomes
$$ G'' + G' * \int_{0}^{\eta} G d\eta + (1-G^2)\beta = 0\\
G(0) = f'(0)= 0\\
G(\infty=n) = 1$$
The nonlinear part in the RHS has been approximated as:
$$(G^2 - 1) = 2G_{{j}_{old}}G_{j} - (G_{{j}_{old}})^2 - 1$$
G_{j_{old}} is the previous guess in the iterative scheme.
We then use the central differences rules for G and write the equation in terms of $G_{j-1}, G_j, G_{j+1}$ over a non-uniform grid of n grid points from 0 to $\eta_n$ i.e. $\eta_j$ where j varies from 0 to n. The equation is something like this,
$$a_j G_{j-1} + b_j G_j +c_j G_{j+1} = -(G_{j_{old}}^2+1)\beta$$
And the tridiagonal matrix equation looks like this,
\begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix}
    b_2 & c_2 & 0 & 0 & - & -\\
    a_3 & b_3 & c_3 & 0 & - & - \\
    0 & a_4 & b_4 & c_4 & 0 & -\\
    0 & 0 & a_5 & b_5 & c_5 & -\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & - & - & - \\
    - & - &- & a_{n-2} & b_{n-2} & c_{n-2}\\
    - & - & - & - & a_{n-1} & b_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix}  \times \begin{bmatrix}
    G_2 \\ G_3 \\ G_4\\ G_5\\-\\-\\ G_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -\beta(1+G^{old^2}_{2})-a_2 G_1 \\ -\beta(1+G^{old^2}_{3}) \\ -\beta(1+G^{old^2}_{4})\\ -\beta(1+G^{old^2}_{5})\\-\\-\\ -\beta(1+G^{old^2}_{n-1}) - c_{n-1} G_n
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
And, now we use the Thomas algorithm to invert the following equation and find $G (or f')$ from this,
$$ AG = R $$

I solve this in Fortran and my results look like this:
[image: Velocity profiles I got]
They are supposed to look like this
[image: Correct velocity profiles]

I am unable to understand why this works for positive values of $\beta$ but fails for negative and zero.

Comment: But does it really work for positive $β$? Apart from having the asymptotic shape, the values do not look similar. $β=1.0$ by the reference visually converges shortly after $η=2$, but in your plot only after $η=3$. The graph for $β=0.3$ in your plot converges too early at about $η=1$, while in the reference convergence is only shortly before $η=3$.

Comment: It does not exactly converge at the right $\eta$ but atleast the solution matches qualitatively. For negative and 0 values of $\beta$ it is just completely wrong. I have been through the formulation and code many times and I am not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: How do you compute the integral, it should be at least the trapezoidal method? Have you checked that the linearization is a correct fixed-point equation to the end? How would you think about using a "proper" linearization à la Newton?

Comment: The likely answer is that non-linear boundary-value problems can have multiple solutions. For negative $β$ the asymptotic solution becomes unstable, so that the solver tends to converge to some other non-asymptotic solution.

Comment: When the solution becomes unstable do we see this particular stable solution due to the method that is used here? If one uses a shooting method with Runge Kutta, would this still be the case?

Comment: The integral is computed using the trapezoidal approximation and the linearization is the Newton's method, but I am ignoring the term quadratic in the error $(G−Gold)^2$. I am not sure what this means--> 'correct fixed-point equation to the end'.

Comment: The fixed-point is probably not a concern, it was asking if in the linearizations and simplifications some terms are lost so that a different fixed-point problem is solved, giving a lower approximation order or no approximation at all. // A solution in itself is not stable or unstable, that depends mostly on the solution method. So what is unstable here could be stable for some other method. In some other cases and methods the stability might switch with a change of the time direction (using single shooting as fixed-point map for $y'=y^3+\sin(t)$).

Comment: Sorry, but what does the $\times$ between the two matrices represent? Is this supposed to be normal matrix multiplication?

Comment: It is just a matrix representation for the system of equations, multiplying the matrices will give us our system. So it is the symbol for product, yes. It is an unnecessary symbol maybe.