# How to solve a third order nonlinear ODE (Falkner-Skan wedge equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How can I solve the following ODE numerically
$$F'''+FF''+1-F'^2=0$$
$$F(0)=F'(0)=0\qquad F'(\infty)=1$$
Thank you.

Comment: You could mention that this is one case of the Falkner-Skan equation. With that key word you can find topics like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158604/solve-falkner-skan-numerically, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884444/falkner-skan-solution-using-a-tridiagonal-matrix,

Comment: The idea of a "far field approximation" like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610416/how-to-solve-an-ode-with-y-1-term could also be relevant, up to now I have not found a non-trivial application to this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [How do you solve this kind of third order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195903),

Let $U=(F')^2$ ,

Then $\pm\sqrt U\dfrac{d^2U}{dF^2}+F\dfrac{dU}{dF}-2U+2=0$